# Prototype into a Closure Object

Tags: javascript, closures

So, as a work requirement our code cannot be larger than 80 columns and 250 rows. This means I have to go back and break up my code into smaller files and I am exploring a few options. First that came to mind was `prototyping` with JavaScript since I can't install `RequireJS`. Secondly, my application uses a closure. My question is this: can you prototype into a closure? Example below.

> File #1

```
var app = (function () {
  var _userName = "Steve";
  function sayHello() {
    return "Hello " + _userName;
  }
  return {
    sayHello: sayHello
  }
})();
```

> File #2

```
app.prototype.sayGoodbye = function() {
  return "Goodbye " + _userName;
};
```

> Output

```
app.sayHello(); // should output "Hello Steve"
app.sayGoodbye(); // should output "Goodbye Steve"
```

However this does not seem to work, because the `sayGoodbye()` function is not included in the closure. But, if told the `sayHello()` function to use the `sayGoodbye()`, that also does not work. Any suggestions on how to construct a closure object across multiple files? Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that `var app;` is not returning an app object to do a prototype

Comment: So, what if I did `(function app () { ... })();` then assign that to a variable, would that do the trick?

Comment: wait for it, I'm writing an answer

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with prototypes. Absolutely nothing. Forget them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - extract out function while keeping it private](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23364382/1048572) or [How do I give multiple JavaScript objects across multiple files access to same private variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35529674/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `closure function` like this, this is a `closure function` that seems more like a `class`

```js
var app = (function() {

  // This is your constructor
  function app() {
    this._userName = "Steve";
  }

  function hello() {
    return "Hello " + this._userName;
  }

  // This is made to do the above function hello() public
  app.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    return hello.call(this);
  }

  // Here we return the app object to be able to do a prototype
  return app;
})();

// Here we do our prototype
app.prototype.sayGoodbye = function() {
  return "Goodbye " + this._userName;
}

// Here we create an instance
var a = new app();

console.log(a.sayHello()); // should output "Hello Steve"
console.log(a.sayGoodbye()); // should output "Goodbye Steve"
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I am going to give this a shot and report back. What if I wanted to use a single variable?

Comment: well, like my answer shows, you can create an instance of app and use it through all your code

Comment: Ohhh I see. Duh. Need more sleep! Thank you!